# TypeScript Custom typeguard returns false even when it is the correct type

Tags: typescript

So I recently started learning TypeScript and I've been trying to include typeguards but they don't seem to work. So the way I have it laid out is I have an interface called `IColor` set up like:

```js
interface IColor {
    r:number;
    g:number;
    b:number;
}
```

and I have a concrete implementation called `Color` set up like:

```js
class Color implements IColor {
    static IsColor = (obj:any):obj is IColor => typeCheck<IColor>(obj, "r", "g", "b");

    r:number;
    g:number;
    b:number;

    ... (rest of the class)
}
```

and `typeCheck<T>` looks like this:

```js
export const typeCheck = <T>(objToCheck:any, ...props:Array<keyof T>):objToCheck is T => {
    let isType:boolean = true;
    for(let prop in props){
        if(!propertyCheck(objToCheck, prop)){
            isType = false;
        }
    }
    return isType;
}

export const propertyCheck = <T>(objToCheck:any, prop:keyof T):objToCheck is T => (objToCheck as T)[prop] !== undefined;
```

But when I call `Color.IsColor({r: 100, g: 0, b: 0})` or even if I call it with a Color object like `Color.IsColor(new Color(100, 0, 0))` I get `false` even though it has all of the properties being checked. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it seems I was just being dumb and I need to use a `for...of` loop instead of a `for...in` loop

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here:

```
for(let prop in props){
```

`props` is an array, and `for/in` iterates keys, not values. So `for (let prop in props)` means that `prop` is `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, etc.

Change that to iterate values via `for/of` and it should work like you expect.

```
for(let prop of props){
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=5&pln=23&pc=28#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2AbTVkDeAUMqclAFwgCuAtgEbQDcJZA5lXY1C2cvZwbMiAXyJEE2OAGdpyLLnzBaAB2wRaEcHIw48hVqWlg4YYAjTSF+gLzIAFJnoArCnBABPAJQUnz5MA61vg2AHzIYB4qEOgAFhAIANYAPLqKoY4uADTIAERQuTm5bIV59LleTMjifJTINEI8hsgc9VzCfAJtjSzNCJggxlDUCGB49l4GfHxgsYEAdCHIAAzNM3PS82zIdqvTZLML9DsrzWJiEgPGEVEx8UknyQAqGX5PmHEJiW6eOfP-KigmBU0goAEEoFA4B5kokIB5MDBkC8fG8PvdEgE5E8duFiHx1GAsU9bhR6JgcBB3CcwMMILwyDBxoTkIDgchEaygSCvPj9gEkfYAIRs6JQSKfJKZZzvSWJHKiryTPn8siBEnRE7wbDSelrMhiPiGshQCBgahQEDE24sC79QZE0XQCUYx4vezNNFyijIdweLLNUU+uEIpFPIg+DkuWWuwLI3EOL2umTIrwAbVFAF1kEKbHZqCAACYQGCgCCF3r26SU+a4Nj2YLzVBWPRQewEOoARmWyxyrV7-B9yxESqAA)